# How do I remove certain items from Windows Explorer's navigation pane?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

How do I get the following directories (or "directories") to never show up in Windows Explorer again?:

> <s>Favorites</s>
>
> Desktop
>   →<s>Libraries</s>
>   →<s>Homegroup</s>
>   →User
>   →→<s>Desktop</s>
>   →→Documents
>   →→Downloads
>   →→<s>Favorites</s>
>   →→<s>Links</s>
>   →→My Music
>   →→My Pictues
>   →→My Videos
>   →→<s>Searches</s>
>   →Computer
>   →<s>Network</s>
>   →Control Panel
>   →Trash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tool [Windows 7 Navigation Pane Customizer](http://www.door2windows.com/windows-7-navigation-pane-customizer-show-hide-rename-items-in-windows-explorer-navigation-pane/) allows you to select which items you want to see or not:

[image]